# unable to establish a CKRecord variable - prepare for segue

Tags: swift, variables, segue

So im seguing a variable "detail" from the previous table controller and adding the receiving variable to my new view controller.

```
    if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? Detail {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        destViewController.detail = restaurants[indexPath.row]
```

The variable "detail" is holding an instance of a CKRecord from the previous table.  However, when I attempt to create a variable of the same name in the view controller, I am unable to establish itself without errors.  For example, I tried

```
var detail: CKRecord!
```

However, I get the error "use of undeclared CKRecord".  How would I go about to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to import CloudKit into your `Detail` controller so that Xcode knows what a `CKRecord` is:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class Detail: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Model

    var model: CKRecord

    // MARK: - Other stuff

    ...

}
```

Comment: That would probably do it!  However, why is it that I still need to import cloud kit if I segue the instance from the table view with the cloud kit to a variable in the proceeding view controller?  Does it just work like that?

Comment: Because the `import` statement in Swift only imports the symbols of the foreign module into the file with the `import` statement. This means you'll have to add the `import CloudKit` in any Swift file where you want to use CloudKit functionality.